# How to change menuitem header by selected tabcontrol item

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF windows form I have menuitem and TabControl. I would like to change contents header of menuitem when TabControl item selected. If it is possible. How to do that in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any code behind or `ViewModel` usage if you want.

We simply bind the `MenuItem`s `Header` property to the selected tab item header.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Height="32">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding ElementName=MyTabControl, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
    </Menu>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Name="MyTabControl">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1Header"/>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2Header"/>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```